# Jquery find+length/size returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, href

I have some divs created dynamically this way:

```
 //here goes some loop, and everything works fine
 $("#result_main_search").append('<div class="singleresult_main_search">
 <a href="http://somesite.com/" class="linktosight">'
  + SightsList[i]+ '</a>  –  ' + 
'<img src="/images/balloon.gif" rel="'+ i 
 +'" class="balloon_img_main_search" /></div>');
```

After that loop, I try to set href attribute for each link:

```
$('.singleresult_main_search').each(function() {
  $.get("_ajax_get_sight_link.php", {'id':$("img", this).attr('rel')}, 
   function(data) { 
     alert($(this).find('.linktosight').length);
     $(this).find('a').attr('href', data);    
     alert(data);
   });
})
```

`_ajax_get_sight_data.php` accepts id, returns link *( alert(data) works fine)* . 
But alert which tells how much .linktosight elements are in current div always gives 0 (by saying always I mean everytime it finds one of my generated divs). I've tried `.size()`, `$(this).find('a')` with the same result. So, how am I to set it to work?

Comment: After some revision, I got that $(this) inside function(data) doesn't relate to my div, so I put it before $.get and everything works fine. But how am I now to access href property of a in this?

Comment: Would [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) be of use, perhaps?

Comment: is there a breakline between `'<div class="singleresult_main_search">` and
`<a href="http://somesite.com/" class="linktosight">'` ? Because there shouldn't be

Comment: @Alex store `this` to a variable and use that variable insidge $.get.

Comment: Could you use `$(data)` on the AJAX response to wrap it in a jQuery object, then use normal `$(data).find('a').attr('href')` to access the href property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside the callback will point to the jqXHR-object and not to the looped elements.

You may create a closure:

```
$('.singleresult_main_search').each(function() {
var $this=$(this);
//.....
});
```

..and use it inside the callback:

```
function(data) { 
     alert($this.find('.linktosight').length);
   });
```

$.proxy() may also be an option like suggested by  Jack Franklin